# how to compare two date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

> I'm having a hard time in comparing two date in laravel, I try this code
>   below in mysql and it works well but when I transfer it on laravel it doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM `holiday` WHERE date_format(holiday.date,'%m-%d') = date_format('2017-05-15','%m-%d')
```

> here is my code in laravel

```
public function getHoliday(){
 $date = '2017-05-15';

         $data = DB::table('holiday')
         ->select(
            'holiday.id'
            )
        ->whereRaw("date_format(holiday.date, '%m-%d') "=" date_format($date, '%m-%d')")

        ->first();



        return $data;

    }
```

> I do hope you could help me with my code, I just want to compare day and month of two date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = DB::table('holiday')
    ->select([
        'holiday.id',
        'holiday.date',
    ])
    ->whereRaw("date_format(holiday.date, '%m-%d') = date_format('$date', '%m-%d')")
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line :

```
->whereRaw("date_format(holiday.date, '%m-%d') "=" date_format($date, '%m-%d')")
```

to this

```
 ->where(date_format(holiday.date, '%m-%d') , date_format($date, '%m-%d'))
```

EDIT.

try to use this date helpers instead

```
          ->whereDay('date', '=', date('d'))
          ->whereMonth('date', '=', date('m'))
          ->first();
```

Comment: still not working, it gives me an error "date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given"

Comment: you declare your date as a string .. change this `$date = '2017-05-15';` to this `$date = date('m-d') `

Comment: Shouldn't the = sign be in the same quotes? Like: ->whereRaw("date_format(holiday.date, '%m-%d') = date_format($date, '%m-%d')")